# Pagination using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: accessibility, pagination, page

On Vimeo.com, you could paginate using keyboard arrows, if you want to. I haven't seen this functionality on any other website. Is keyboard pagination a good option? I'm wondering since I only see it on Vimeo.

Comment: Keyboard controls in general are a good idea for accessibility as long as they conform well known standards - adding keyboard controls that require some level of thought (an example might be using 'T' go forward one page and '9' to go back) are going to cause more trouble for your users. Consult accepted sources such as your local low-vision support organisation for guidance about what keys should be used to control particular functions. Other than that this question is probably too broad or open to opinion to answer.

Comment: @AndrewMartin better to delete it?

Comment: If you're referring to the question then no, there are more than 80,000 users registered here so they may have a view on your question that is different from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard pagination is something you probably don't see much because the sites that heavily employ keyboard controls are the ones that use infinite scrolling.

However, when it comes to accessibility, keyboard shortcuts are a must. Many users with motor or vision disabilities rely on a keyboard. Think of tab to move between input fields and buttons. A website must be built with accessibility in mind, because the structure is often different from a standard website.

These standardised shortcuts however are mainly related to navigation and not shortcuts for workflows. For more specific features, it remains quite difficult to tie a keyboard shortcut to an action. Shortcuts will differ from website to website, meaning keyboard shortcuts request a certain type of familiarity with the system before it can be used. They're too reliant on expertise which frankly most users will never develop simply due to too little exposure. There are of course exceptions; [Sites like Facebook have more extensive accessibility shortcuts for their navigation, partly due to their user base spending more time on their website.](https://www.facebook.com/help/156151771119453)